# Cannot store the answer to memory in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm trying to write a function in MIPS that would take in a string and return the number of character inside the string. This is what I have so far

```
# Program to calculate string length of any given string

            .data
mystring:   .asciiz "Hello, World!"
answer:     .word 0

            .text
            .globl main
main:       la      $a0, mystring   # Load base adress of the string into function argument

            jal     strlen          # jump to strlen and save position to $ra

            sw      $vo, answer     # Store the answer to memory

            li      $v0, 10         #exit
            syscall


strlen:     li      $v0, 0          # Initialize counter = 0

stringLoop: lb      $t0, 0($a0)     # Load first word of the string

            beq     $t0, $zero, end # if $t0 == '\0' then exit the loop

            addi    $a0, $a0, 1     # Increment the address (go to the next character)

            addi    $v0, $v0, 1     # Increment the counter

            b       stringLoop

end:        jr      $ra             # Return to main program
```

Everytime I try to run it with QtSpim, it gives me a syntax error at the line "sw      $vo, answer". Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my program? Thanks

Comment: Presumably the QTspim assembler isn't willing to treat it as a pseudo-instruction and turn it into `lui` + `sw` with the two halves of the 32-bit absolute address for you.  Use `la`.  If you put it *before* `mystring` you could address it relative to the pointer you load into `$a0` earlier, but since you put it after there's implicit alignment padding.  (Which you could hard-code the size of if you wanted, or e.g. `addiu $s0, $a0, answer-mystring` if your assembler allows that, to save a pointer before your `strlen` destroys its $a0 input)

Comment: There is no such thing as `vo` register, but `v0`. Maybe typo?

Comment: Oh lol, or that would do it.

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot, that's a typo, that fixed my problem.

Comment: maybe someboy could write an answer.

Comment: @Mike: typo problem questions should generally get closed as "trivial - typo", not answered.  Future users with the same problem generally can't find them by searching because they don't know what to search on.  (If they did, they'd just fix their typo.)  Questions that aren't going to help future readers aren't worth having around, cluttering up SO search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax errors are often caused by typos as in your case. You accidentally wrote `vo` instead of `v0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent almost 30 mins just for this problem alone. I may need to find a good text editor that does syntax highlighting for MIPS assembly.